# If the value of the dropdown contains unpaid, the other dropdowns will be readonly automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html

What I wanted to do is that when the value of the dropdown paymentstatus is unpaid, the other two dropdowns automatically won't be clicked. My code is working is just that I need to click the dropdown for the code to work since I'm using onclick. Is there any other way that I don't have to click the dropdown?

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Order Status</label>
                     <?php
                        require '../includes/db.php';
                        $sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM orderstatus");
                        $sql->execute();
                        $data = $sql->fetchAll();
                        echo "<select name='orderstatusid' id='orderstatusid' class='form-control orderstatusid' required>";
                        foreach($data as $row):
                            echo "<option class='dropdown' value='{$row['orderstatusid']}'>".htmlspecialchars($row["description"])."</option>";
                        endforeach;
                        echo "</select>";
                     ?>
                     <br />
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-3">
                 <label>Payment Status</label>
                     <?php
                        require '../includes/db.php';
                        $sql = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM paymentstatus");
                        $sql->execute();
                        $data = $sql->fetchAll();
                        echo "<select name='paymentstatusid' id='paymentstatusid' class='form-control paymentstatusid' onchange='disableotherdropdown()' required>";
                        foreach($data as $row):
                            echo "<option class='dropdown' value='{$row['paymentstatusid']}'>".htmlspecialchars($row["description"])."</option>";
                        endforeach;
                        echo "</select>";
                     ?> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                 <label>Date of Payment</label>
                 <input type="date" name="paiddate" id="paiddate" class="form-control paiddate" required/>
                 <br />
                </div>
             </div>



    <script>
       function disableotherdropdown() {
            var val = $(".paymentstatusid").val();
            if (val != '1') {
                $('.paiddate').css('border-color', 'red');
                $('.orderstatusid').attr("readonly", false); 
                $('.paiddate').attr("readonly", false);
            } else {
                $('.orderstatusid').attr("readonly", true); 
                $('.paiddate').attr("readonly", true);
                $('.paiddate').css('border-color', '#ccc');
            }

       }

    </script>
```

Comment: Are these `<select>` editable by the user? I don't think that's possible, readonly means the user can't edit its text. I believe you want `$('select').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: May be this is Dom loading issue   
window.onload = disableotherdropdown()

Comment: Have u tried this window.load for first time to check without click request to disable other fields

Comment: <option selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>. Set default value as empty and try for paymentstatus before for each loop

Comment: @gowthamrajan i tried the window.onload = disableotherdropdown() but when the paymentstatus is paid it doesn't read the code: ```if (val != '1') {
                $('.paiddate').css('border-color', 'red');
                $('.orderstatusid').attr("readonly", false); 
                $('.paiddate').attr("readonly", false);```

val= 1 is unpaid val= 2 is paid

Comment: 1. On page load complete you have to call  window.load = disableotherdropdown() this will check initially after php or dom content loads all.     2. You need to check on change event or click event of a dropdown when select value changes by user

Comment: Check if(Val != 1) as checking integer type

Comment: @gowthamrajan I've changed ``if(Val != 1)`` and put ``window.onload = disableotherdropdown() ``. It works if the value of the paymenstatus is unpaid so it reads the else code. However if it is paid, it does the same like all are disabled which shouldn't be.

Comment: Console.log(Val) the value wat u getting at initial   and on click change  any undefined is coming

Comment: Hi i updated sample code

Comment: In  HTML specs, the select tag in HTML doesn't have a readonly attribute, only a disabled attribute.  Set hidden field for orderstatusid and paiddate value on paymentstatusid change  to pass disabled field value on form submit

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#paymentstatusid").change(function() 
 {disableotherdropdown()});
 function disableotherdropdown(){
 var val =$("#paymentstatusid").val();
          alert(val)
          if (val !=1) {
             alert('a');
              $('#orderstatusid').attr("disabled",false); 
          } else {
            alert('b');  
       $('#orderstatusid').attr("disabled", true); 
    }
    }
   });
  </script>
  <body>
    <select id='paymentstatusid'>
     <option selected val='0'>hhh</option>
      <option value='1'>paid</option>
     <option value='2'>unpaid</option>
    </select>
   <select id='orderstatusid'>
     <option selected="selected" val='0' >&nbsp;</option>
     <option val='1'>a</option>
     <option val='2'>b</option>
  </select>
  </body>
```

Change
Readonly to disable works
$('#orderstatusid').attr("disabled", true);